# How can I get legend from Arcgis MapServer url

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, leaflet, legend, arcgis-online-basemaps

İs it possible to get legend item from arcgis mapserver or feature url. For example `http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer`

I can use legends if I use esri javascript api. But I am using openlayers or leaflet. So I have to get legend item of a layer.

Comment: relevant discussion: https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Legend_Map_Service/02r3000000pm000000/

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/legend

Add the parameters: "f" and "dynamicLayers" as described in the above link.